# Free tool for RGB PDF separation into R, G, B?

Tags: gratis, pdf, color

Can i separate RGB PDF into three color's pdfs using LaTeX or GS or any other free tool?

As fas as i can see, it's quite possible for CMYK (`tiffsep`/`gs`), so what about RGB pdfs?

I mean "any PDF" which may contain embedded eps or other vector graphics as well as raster images.

Preferred OSes are Linux (the first choice) and Windows.

Comment: Not tried, but AFAIR *Gimp* can separate that, and it can also import PDFs. As I haven't tried that myself, I cannot make it an (detailed) answer, but you might wish to see for yourself. *Gimp* is available on Linux (from the default repos) and Windows (even as portable).

Comment: @Izzy, thank you, i didn't think about GIMP (and its batch mode!), it's interesting indeed. However, regarding _separation_, it will take a lot of _manual work_, because multipage pdfs will be imported as layers, then those layers are to be separated into RGB _each_ and then i have to check every R in multiple (separation) images, then every G and then B, so... Well, it's a task for scheme programming, i'd say. Thank you anyway. )

Comment: I didn't promise it'd be easy :) As an idea: You could split the PDF by pages first, and then deal with each page separately – which at least should avoid the "mess of thousand layers." Unless someone comes up with a better solution, that is.

Comment: @Izzy, no i'd rather play with python-fu, it's easier for me than scheme .) Okay, thank you for the hint, i'll share my solution when (if) i'll succeed. Thanks)